# Fetching values via foreign keys with DataMapper

Tags: ruby, foreign-keys, datamapper

I have two tables, `nodes` and `terms`.

The relevant fields in `nodes` are: `nid` (primary key) and `value`
In `terms`, they are: `value`, `tid`, and `nid`, where `value` and `tid` together are the primary key and `nid` is a foreign key referencing `nodes.nid`.

I want to add records to `terms`. I have the `tid` and `nid`, and the `value` I want to pull from the corresponding `node` - e.g. look up the `value` for a given `nid` in `node` and then put that as the `value` in `terms`.

A way to do this in SQL might be:

```
INSERT INTO terms(tid, nid, value)
values(mytid, mynid, (
    select value from nodes where nid=mynid
));
```

Could somebody help me do this with DataMapper?

```
class Node
    include DataMapper::Resource

    property :nid,    Serial,  :key => true
    property :value,  Integer

end


class Term
    include DataMapper::Resource

    property :tid,    Integer, :key => true

    # how do I define nid and value?
end

# and then what do I give to Term.new or Term.create and how?
```

If anyone could point me to a good tutorial of DataMapper as well, I'd appreciate it. I've been using their online docs, but I've found the situations I find myself in are rarely covered there.

Comment: I found the doc's OK, but support on IRC was great.  Check out the following question I had.  The answer explained how to do relationships and query against them. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826439/beginning-with-datamapper-association-question

Answer (score 1):

From your description the models you're looking for should be setup like that:

```
class Node
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :nid,    Serial
  property :value,  Integer
end

class Term
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :tid,   Integer, :key => true
  property :value, Integer, :key => true

  belongs_to :node, :child_key => :nid
end
```

You can work with these models like that:

```
# create a node
node = Node.create(:value => 123)

# create a term and associate it with the node
term = Term.create(:tid => 321, :node => node, :value => node.value)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is this really the only way to do it? Because that's how I considered doing it in the first place, but I thought there might be a way, if I defined the models well, that I could do Term.create(:tid => 321, :nid=>999) and it would, internally, convert that to "lookup nid 999 using Node, then insert tid=321,nid=999,vid=whatever you found there". I can make a method within Term to do that and hide the details, but I thought that might be something DataMapper could handle with a well flushed-out model. Maybe that's asking a lot.

Comment: You can set up a before save hook which would do self.value = node.value